# Android Bootstrap and Android studio cannot add library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-bootstrap-widgets

I would like to add the [Android Bootstrap library](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap) to my project using Android Studio (I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCKWIDGULfY)).

I see Android Bootstrap and my project in project explorer, but if I try to add a bootstrap button

```xml
 <!-- basic button -->
    <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Success"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-android"
        bootstrapbutton:bb_type="success"
        />
```

I get the following error message:

> android-apt-compiler: layout/activity_main.xml:56: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'bb_icon_right' in package 'com.carfinder'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Make sure your project structure should look like this, your library can be inside some directory, like libraries>AndroidBootStrapLibrary no problem, in that case only you have to change path in settings.gradle and build.gradle

```
    ----YOUR_PROJECT
       ---AndroidBootStrapLibrary
         --res
         --src
         -- .....
         -- build.gradle(must contain apply plugin: 'android-library' 
            if not that menas not library project you have added something wrong)
       ---YOUR_MODULE
         --res
         --src
         --build.gradle (no : A)
   ----settings.gradle
```

build.gradle (No. A) file

```
  dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
       compile project(':AndroidBootStrapLibrary')
  }
```

settings.gradle :

```
  include ':YOUR_MODULE'
  include ':AndroidBootStrapLibrary'
```

Do sync Project with Gradle after all

[image: sync project with gradle]

You forgot to add namespace for the custom view in library.

Replave your code for button with this

```
     <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
         xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:text="Success"
         bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-android"
         bootstrapbutton:bb_type="success"
    />
```

add namespace in other views too if you are using. You can also add it in to the root element of your layout file too like

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

     <TextView
         android:text="@string/hello_world"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:text="Success"
         bootstrapbutton:bb_icon_right="fa-android"
         bootstrapbutton:bb_type="success"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

I have uploaded one working test project here (Checkout form github in AS)

https://github.com/pyus-13/TesstApp.git

Comment: Unfortunately this not solving the problem. I got the same error message. If i try to Fix Build path (check gen and andoid-support-v4 options) i got message. 

Error running build: Module 'AndroidBootstrap' is not backed by gradle

Maybe this is causing the problem, but i don't know how to solve this (i have not experiences with Gradle) .

Comment: It is working in my project perfectly. please post your ide library screen shot and also build.gradle and settings.gradle file.

Comment: I have uploaded my Test project on Github https://github.com/pyus-13/TesstApp import it in your studio and check.

Comment: Hello, here is the screenshot
http://postimg.org/image/cpvu1sqnp/

I tried to add android-bootstrap via gradle wizard in Android studio.

It implements more items then before, but activity xml with defined button is still showing errors. 

Could You please provide step-by-step what do make it works?

Comment: https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/tree/master/AndroidBootstrap is this the BootStrap you are using ?

Comment: Yep, it is BootStrap plugin which i like to implement.

Comment: have you tried the sample test app which i have uploaded on github, Delete the Bootstrap library you are having in your project and add the one in my sample. Clean and Rebuild your project i have mention step by step configuration in my updated answer. Seems like you are added the test project of bootstrap not the library in your project.

Comment: check my updated answer(edit in project structure comments in build.gradle file ) for verifying whether you have added the library or test project.

Comment: Interesting, Your git Example is working fine after import. But i still not able to get work in my project. I thought that library should not be attached in project (i always worked with linked library). Is need to rum some Gradle scripts for successful installation of Bootstrap? Gradle is new for me and i would like to avoid using them for now.

Comment: It is very easy. Delete yours one from your project. Delete the android-bootstrap directory and dependency if added. Now copy androidbs from my project to root and then have a look to my build.gradle file dependency in app module and settings.gradle. After doing all sync Project with gradle.

Comment: I copied sources to root dir, updated /app/settings.gradle, checked androiddbs in libray (is available but is not compliled by Gradle?).

How can i please do all sync Project with gradle ?

Comment: Thanks, i tried to sync project with gradle, it seems to be fine. After rebuild, buttons seems to be working correctly. 

Many thanks for Your help.

BTW: Gradle seems to be quite annoing (build takes more time, more difficult, etc..), but i hope, that it is only temporarily :)

Comment: its not difficult, its new for you. Actually you are no much used to, once you will start using it, it will be fun. This is the future of build system, soon all the library will be added in maven repo afterwards you dont need to download anything just a single line in dependency will do all the things like charm.

Comment: Agree, just one question. I add folder fontawesome into
app/src/main/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf

And rebuild, but no icon has been appeared in button. Is need to set something?

Comment: sorry did not get you, If you have any other question keep it in separate Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody is trying to add this library and comes across this question but has different issues, I think it would be worth mentioning the full steps that worked for me (I adapted the wiki from [another library](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio) here):

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Download the library (using Git, or a zip archive to unzip)
3. Go to the folder where you unzipped the library > AndroidBootstrap > build.gradle
4. Remove 'apply from: 'push.gradle'
5. Replace *Integer.parseInt(TARGET_SDK_INT), Integer.parseInt(MIN_SDK_INT), Integer.parseInt(VERSION_CODE), VERSION_NAME,  "25.0.1"* with the versions from your project. You can find those in Gradle Scripts > build.gradle
6. Go to File > Import Module and import the library (you only need the *AndroidBootstrap* folder, not the whole code from the branch)
7. Go to File > Project Structure
8. Locate your main project module, click on it. (you should also see AndroidBootstrap below it)
9. Click on it and go to Dependencies.
10. Click on the left green "+" button > Module dependency
11. Select "AndroidBoostrap"

And now everything should work.

You might still get an error in your .xml files when you try to add an element from the AndroidBoostrap library "Namespace 'app' is not bound.". You can solve this by clicking ALT + ENTER on the error in Android Studio, or add this line

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

after the declaration or your Layout and xmlns:tools e.g

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

I don't know if this is the most accurate solution on how to include a library as I am an Android beginner but it worked for me.